# onListItemClick and CheckedTextView not respoding

Tags: android

I got `ListActivity`, each item has 2 textviews image and `CheckedTextView`. I am trying to implement simple multichoiselist...
I have two problems:
1.

```
     @Override
      protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v,
        int position, long id)
             {
                ...
              }
```

doesnt respond at all I have tried it with the debugger and when I press on any list item it doesnt stop there. and I have tried all kind of things (like `focusable:false`)

two:. 
          I cant toggle the `CheckedTextView` anyhow.

here is my xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100sp"
android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
android:padding="6dip">

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:id="@drawable/icon" android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false">


</ImageView>


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="1sp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/toptext" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" android:text="OrderNum"
        android:singleLine="true" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    </TextView>



    <TextView android:id="@+id/bottomtext" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:text="TweetMsg">
    </TextView>


    <TextView android:id="@+id/twittLocation"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:text="location" android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
    </TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/twittLocationlink"
        android:text="locationlink" android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
    </TextView>





</LinearLayout>




<CheckedTextView android:id="@android:id/text1"  android:text="Delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"

    android:focusable="false"></CheckedTextView>



</LinearLayout>
```

any idea what's the problem?
thanks.

Comment: Use `LogCat` and leave debug statements inside your code to see if its being registered. Once you do that, open the `LogCat` perspective window and see what happens inside the window.

Comment: What should i look for in the logcat? nothing is written there which concern the problem of mine, 
what has to be registered? could u be more specific please

Comment: That might be a separate problem, which has been addressed here before. Do an SO search for "logcat messages don't show up" or something like that.

Comment: By the way, there's an extra `>` in your XML.

Answer (score 0):

In your ListView set `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class Sample extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener{

ListView list;

list.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {


            }

        });

}
```

[Sample code](http://androidgreeve.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-sliding-menu.html)